# Error in connecting oracle 11G in localhost using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

```java
import java.sql.*;

public class one {

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
            Connection conn=null;
        Statement stmt=null;

        try
        {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/ecom","system","manager");
        stmt=conn.createStatement();
        String str="insert into country values(3,'bangladesh');";
        int k=stmt.executeUpdate(str);
        System.out.println(k);
            }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
    }
```

The only jar file I added to the class path is `ojdbc6.jar` is there any other jar required for connecting with `oracle 11g(11.2.0.1.0)` I am using eclipse as IDE

here are the errors

```
java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:412)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:221)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at one.main(one.java:17)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:359)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:422)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:672)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:237)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1042)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:301)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocket`Impl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:141)
```

Comment: It seems you don't have any oracle database running on your machine and listening on port 1521.

Comment: And don't use `;` in your query..it is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

1) Please be sure database host name, port number, or database instance name are correct.
2) Be sure the TNSListener has been started ( run lsnrctl start)

Comment: Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
 TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error

Comment: in your SQLNET.ORA file, please ensure that: SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)

Comment: where is this SQLNET.ORA file and what is the default port number for 11g and how to change this port number?

Comment: Under your oracle installation, just look for a path like this: network\admin\sqlnet.ora to find the file. The default port is as you wrote 1521.

Comment: #sqlnet.authentication_services
#
# Syntax: A single value or a list from {beq, none, all, kerberos5,
#   cybersafe, radius}
# Default: NONE

Comment: C:\Users\Vilkesh>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on
:16

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   32-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error

Comment: in your listener.ora file, you will find an expression like: (HOST=) please ensure (HOST=localhost)

Comment: LISTENER =
#  (ADDRESS_LIST=
#       (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))
#       (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=PNPKEY)))

Comment: Glad for you. What was the problem ?

Comment: it was a silly mistake i didn't configure the listener from Oracle Net Configuration Assistant in configuration and migration tools

Answer (score 0):

The connection string is malformed. It should be
"jdbc:oracle:thin://@localhost:1521/ecom"
Notice the transposition of // and @.